# Unique vote, disable revote

Tags: mongodb, database-design, relational-database

I'm building simple Web App where users can vote.
What is the fastest way for checking if user has already voted. I'm interested in both relation databases and document based databases (mongodb,...)

I have few ideas but I am sure they can be improved:

**Relation databases**

Create a seperate table for voting:

```
|userid|articleid|
```

Before incrementing articles vote check if there is a row including both userid and articleid. We have two queries. Is possible to improve this with triggers? For example:

```
|useridarticleid| unique column
```

Before vote generate useridarticleid on application side. Try to insert useridarticleid. Trigger will fire if field is new and it will increment our vote column in article.

**Document based**

This is a bit more trickier. So having document structured like so:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "content": "something",
  "num_votes": 2,
  "votes" : [
               "userid1",
               "userid2"
             ]
}
```

First "query" - check if userid is in votes array. Second "query" - Increment num_votes if not.

Again two queries. So I thought we can change this but I don't know really if it will increase performance:

Insert userid in votes array. When user want to check article "count" votes in array. But I think it possible that performance will drop because if traffic is high counting every article is a bit of waste. Imagine Reddit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's a lot simpler in a document database.  Your document structure is perfect for it.

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "content": "something",
  "num_votes": 2,
  "votes" : [
               "userid1",
               "userid2"
             ]
}

db.collection.update(
        {id:"123", votes:{$ne:"userid"}},
        {$push:{"votes":"userid"},$inc:{"num_votes":1}}
);
```

This will *atomically* update record id=123 adding userid to list of voters and incrementing votes by one **only** if userid is not already in the list of votes on this document.

So there is only one query and one update - and they are actually the same operation.

Comment: I don't think you need triggers for relational database case either - just add a unique constraint on the userid, articleid table and any repeated insert into it will simply fail.

Answer (score 1):

In a relational database |userid|articleid| would be the best approach, using both fields as primary keys.

In the second one you can also consider wther putting the votes in the user document, or in the article document.

Anyway, I'd suggest you really focus on creating a design, where changing all this decisions later is easy.

The different ways of designing this, favor things like "A lot of users at the same article at the same time" or "A lot of users in different articles", etc... Until you can see the real usage, you won't have enough information to decide which approach will work best and fastest... So create something that you can easily adapt to whatever information you learn later.

BTW: You might also consider don't counting the votes synchronically. I remember an article (which I can't find) where it mentioned that you tube votes numbers weren't actually "accurate"... They put an estimation of the current votes, and calculated the real number in a background worker thread.

Comment: in a document model incrementing votes when you insert the voter into the array guarantees that the two won't get out of sync. If vote counts are stored separately from voters then to have absolutely accurate count you would need a job to periodically check counts.